# Not able to Show/Write from spark DF read using mongo spark connector.

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read a huge complex document from MongoDB into spark data frame. When I convert this db to json, It works. But If I directly read from MongoDB I am getting the following error : **Caused by: com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast STRING into a DoubleType (value: BsonString{value='NaN'})**

Able to read into DF and do all the processing. Getting error when I try to show it or write to a json/csv.

at mongo$.main(mongo.scala:270) – df.show()

Using sbt for Dependencies 
mongo spark connector: 2.2.1
Scala Version: 2.11.6 Spark version: 2.3.0/2.2.0

Comment: Seems like you're trying to convert string to double. Are you defining a schema in Spark where a field is type Double but the value in MongoDB is String ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wan Bachtiar. I am not defining any schema, I want to use the inferschema option so it can be used for any dataset. I cross-checked and it is double in MongoDB too.

Comment: did you got the solution @Sathish ? if yes please share us the solution, if no I will share my solution to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As described by the error, this is because there is a String value of `"NaN"` which is inferred in the Spark schema as Double type.

There's a value for the field, amongst all the documents that is not Double. for example :

```
{_id:1, foo: 100.00}
{_id:2, foo: 101.00}
{_id:3, foo: 102.00}
{_id:4, foo: 103.00}
...
{_id:99, foo: "NaN"}
{_id:100, foo: 200.00}
```

As you may know, "NaN" means "Not a Number". It is likely during creation of the document that whichever process failed to insert Double, and defaulted into `NaN`.

There are few ways to solve this, depending on your use case:

- Utilise [MongoDB Schema Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) to ensure that the values within the collection has the expected type on insert.
- Perform transformation to clean the data. Query the collection to find the offending field i.e. `{foo: "NaN"}` and update with a desired value i.e. `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar conversion problem. Mongodb takes a sample of 1000 documents to define the scheme. In my case, 1000 documents were not sufficient to cover all cases. I increased the sample size and this solved the problem. [Mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/configuration/)

Code:

```
val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map(
  "database" -> "myDatabase",
  "collection" -> "myCollection",
  "sampleSize" -> "100000"), Some(ReadConfig(sc)))
val df = sc.loadFromMongoDB(readConfig).toDF()
```